# Javascript: Why isnt this if statement running?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Right now i am programming an HTML rhythm game, and i have this function that basically plays the music and fufills the variables for this if statement.
However, when i load the project onto the browser, and hit begin (triggers `loadSong()`), the if statement never triggers. Can you help me?     here is the full script:
updated version:

````
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>FontDash: The Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        button {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display:inline;
            line-height: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <button onclick="loadSong()" class="NOU"id="begin">begin</button>
    <button onclick="songPause()" class="NOU"id="begin">||</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let clickCount = 0
var audio = new Audio('Supernova.mp3');
var songTimer = 0
let songNotPaused = false
let songNotFinished = true
var songStarted = false
var duration = audio.duration;

function loadSong() {
  duration = Math.round(audio.duration);
  console.log(duration)
  document.getElementById("begin").disabled = true;
  songNotFinished = true
  songNotPaused = true
  songStarted = true
  audio.play();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ba6dc9";
}
if (songStarted && songNotPaused) {
  if (songTimer <= duration && songStarted && songNotPaused) {
    songTimer++;
    console.log(songTimer);
  }
}

function songPause() {
  if (songNotPaused && songStarted) {
    audio.pause();
    songNotPaused = false
  } else if (songStarted && !songNotPaused) {
    audio.play()
    songNotPaused = true
  }
}

function clickMax() {
  clickCount += 1
  console.log(clickCount)
  console.log(songTimer)
}
document.onclick = function(event) {
  if (songNotPaused && songNotFinished && songStarted) {
    clickMax();
    console.log('clicked!');
  };
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Not enough code has been posted for anyone to help.

Comment: alr imma edit it

Comment: @Pointy heres full javascript

Comment: Setting `duration` to one thing, and then immediately to another thing, does not make sense. Also your initialization of all those variables happens inside that `loadSong()` function, but your `if` statement immediately depends on the values of the variables. If the function is not called, the variables will not be inialized.

Comment: Because `let songStarted = false`

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a title that summarizes this specific problem. We have hundreds of questions that could be summarized by "Why isnt this if statement running?"

Comment: The `if` statement runs when the page first loads, not after you call `loadSong()`. So the changes to the variables will not be seen.

Comment: Are you sure that the `duration` is greater than `0`?

Comment: ye its 312 cuz i math.rounded supernova.mp3 which is is 312 secs

Comment: You are setting `let songStarted = false` and then you're checking `if (songStarted && songNotPaused) {`. This condition can't be true.

Comment: also @ThomasSablik i had the ```let songStarted = false``` be there because you have to click the "begin" button to trigger loadSong, which will begin the music and set songStarted to true.

Comment: wait a sec let is the problem

Comment: JavaScript is single thread. Nothing can change the value of `songStarted` between `let songStarted = false` and `if (songStarted && songNotPaused) {`. It's impossible. The condition will always be false.

Comment: Can you open your debugger, set some breakpoints and analyze the code flow? A breakpoint at `if (songStarted && songNotPaused) {` should explain you the problem. This line is evaluated once, at the beginning, before the functions could be called. Nothing could set `songStarted` to true before this condition is evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the [timeupdate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) to do your timer thing.

```
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  if (songStarted && songNotPaused) {
    if (songTimer <= duration && songStarted && songNotPaused) {
      songTimer++;
      console.log(songTimer);
    }
  }
});
```

Note that most of the variables that you are creating like songTimer, songStarted, songNotPaused, etc, can be read from the audio object directly.  `audio.currentTime` will always be a better choice than counting seconds.